# What does this firebase documentation mean?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

[Convert an anonymous account to a permanent account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/cpp/anonymous-auth)

> When an anonymous user signs up to your app, you might want to allow
>   them to continue their work with their new account—for example, you
>   might want to make the items the user added to their shopping cart
>   before they signed up available in their new account's shopping cart.
>   To do so, complete the following steps:
>
> 1. When the user signs up, complete the sign-in flow for the user's authentication provider up to, but not including, calling one of the
>      methods. For example, get the user's Google ID token, Facebook access
>      token, or email address and password.
> 2. Get an for the new authentication provider:
> 3. Pass the object to the sign-in user's method:
>
> If the call to succeeds, the user's new account can access the anonymous account's Firebase data.

What does this mean as in what code is actually required (specifically to link an email/password to an anonymous account)? Note the above quoted text is quoted accurately.

I've tried this code but it does not work as expected:

```
firebase::auth::Auth* Auth = firebase::auth::Auth::GetAuth(App);
firebase::auth::User* User = Auth->current_user();
firebase::Future<firebase::auth::User*> Future =
   User->is_anonymous() ?
   User->LinkWithCredential(firebase::auth::EmailAuthProvider::GetCredential(email, password)) :
   auth->CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

Comment: Seems like there is at least one bug in the documentation... "Get an for the new authentication provider"

Comment: Yes, hopefully one of the helpful google firebase engineers will reveal the correct answer to us.

Comment: That indeed looks like it missed "a few" code snippets. Thanks for signaling, I'll raise it internally. Note that there's also a "Send feedback" link at the top of the docs, to send these to us. Luckily the docs for all platforms follow a very similar pattern, so hopefully you'll be able to get somewhere by looking at e.g. the corresponding Android docs until we get it fixed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account

Comment: Yes, I have working code on android - however your C++ api seems to be a bit different - and I'm not psychic so an answer would be appreciated . I've edited the question to show the code that isn't working.

Comment: Use https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account There are a bunch of missing snippets. You can substitute the cpp equivalent APIs. I have filed a report with Firebase Auth docs team.